# My iOS Live App. is caching download links

Tags: ios, caching, download, app-store, nsurlconnection

I have a live app on the apple store now. My app connect to my server to download videos and store them on the device for later use. My server went down yesterday causing my app to crash when trying to connect to the server (this is not my problem I will fix it in the next version to not let the app crash). I solved the server problem and it's up and running now.

The problem is with the users that already installed my app. The app is caching the old broken links! and still crashing. my first and fast solution that I posted on my facebook page is to delete the app and reinstall it. Is there another solution for this. like deleting the app cache or something and how to do it.

What if I released a new version. this will notify users to update. Is that will give the same effect as reinstalling? shall I modify my code to prevent nsurlconnection to cache links before I release the new version?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not prepare your application for this case, then there is nothing you can do other than update it.

You should probably change your caching process to only cache the links once you are sure the content was correctly downloaded.

Also, you will have to add a checking process to see if the current cached linked is broken in order to download the data again, which will correct the crashes experienced by your current users (without troubling the ones with clean data).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go around this situation is to release the new version with the fix and never make the same mistake again.

You might need to delete all the cached links programmatically when the user launches an updated app the first time.

That's the best and fastest solution. There's no way to delete the app cache programmatically and remotely so far.